# IndexDB cursor .onsucess as a promise

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, indexeddb

First of all, I can't find a suitable title for this question - please feel free to edit.

I have the following function that reads objects from indexDb,

```
loadNeededParcels = property => {
    const dbResults = [];
    var readTransaction = this.db
      .transaction("parcelData")
      .objectStore("parcelData");
    readTransaction.openCursor().onerror = e => {
      console.log("open cursor error ", e);
    };
    readTransaction.openCursor().onsuccess = e => {
      const cursor = e.target.result;
      if (cursor) {
        dbResults.push(cursor.value);
        cursor.continue();
      } else {   
        return dbResults;
      }
    };
  };
```

Now when I call this function with a simple function call, for example:

```
console.log(loadNeededParcels('hasData'))
```

The console log is `undefined`. I am guessing this happens because the function does not wait for the cursor to finish and return the `dbResults` variable?

So my question is this - how can I re-write this function as a promise, or rather to wait for the `readTransaction.openCursor().onsucess` to trigger?

So the expected result is for the function to actually return the values read from the database before exiting.

I am using cursors since the `.getAll()` the method is not supported in IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this. Do not call openCursor twice, that creates two requests.

```
function loadNeededParcels(db, property) {
 return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
   var results = [];
   var tx = db.transaction('parcelData');
   tx.onerror = function(event) {
     reject(tx.error);
   };
   var store = tx.objectStore('parcelData');

   // Open a cursor over all items
   var request = store.openCursor();

   request.onsuccess = function(event) {
     var cursor = request.result;
     if(cursor) {
       var value = cursor.value;
       if(value) {
         // Only append defined values to the array
         results.push(cursor.value);
       }

       cursor.continue();
     } else {
       resolve(results);
     }
   };
 });
}

loadNeededParcels(db, 'hasData').then(function(results) {
  console.log('Results', results);
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.error(error);
});
```

Comment: Here you are passing the property as an argument to openCursor - but since the property is not the key, this will not work. Also what does the question mark after property stand for? But yeah, re-wrote the method using your approach with only using openCursor once, and it is a bit faster than before

Comment: It is pseudocode. I don't understand what your code is trying to do. The question mark was supposed to indicate that. Opening a cursor without a range or value parameter means you are iterating over all objects in the store.

Comment: Ah basically retrieve all the records from the db, then return only the records that do not have the passed property as undefined (ie if parcel[property] === undefined)

Comment: Create an index on the property then, and open a cursor on the index. This will implicitly filter out undefined values for you and be significantly faster. Plus, the way your code is currently written does not indicate that this is the objective. You are not even testing if the value is defined.

Comment: Sorry about that, thought that I would keep the question simple without the added filtering logic - so just returning the whole dataset as a promise. So basically just remove the property pseudocode from the anwser and I will accept it

Comment: Sure, glad to help

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution that I ended up using:

```
  loadNeededParcels = property => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      var readTransaction = this.db
        .transaction("parcelData")
        .objectStore("parcelData");
      readTransaction.openCursor().onerror = e => {
        reject(e);
      };
      const dbResults = [];
      readTransaction.openCursor().onsuccess = e => {
        const cursor = e.target.result;
        if (cursor) {
          dbResults.push(cursor.value);
          cursor.continue();
        } else {
          resolve(dbResults);
        }
      };
    });
  };
```

Comment: `.onerror = e => {
        reject(e);
      };` is simply `.onerror = reject;`